# Weird problem with file ownership

Tags: macos, server.app, file

I recently had to move server drives from an OSX 10.6 server to a new Mac mini running Yosemite (10.10.4) and Yosemite server (4.1.3) - meaning I physically unplugged them from the old server and plugged them into the new server.

I am in the process of uniformly reassigning owner:group and ACLs.

I have a few folders that seemed to be locked and do not respond to 'sudo chown *newOwner*:*newGroup*'. Cannot chmod 777 either. On the command line these appear with numbers for owner and group (probably metadata from the old server environ) and with permissions set to 755. `ls -le` does not show an ACL associated with the folder.

Any ideas of how to modify permissions? I have already tried to unlock this in the Finder with no luck.

Alternatively, does anyone know where to find out how Yosemite (and server) handle permissions?  What is the pecking order? Do ACLs trump POSIX permissions?

Oh, one more thing. Pretty sure this folder was copied over from a PC originally. Not sure.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case anyone stumbles upon this question, I did figure it out:

```
sudo chflags -Rv nouchg
```

This command recursively strips finder file locks from a directory.

Comment: But -1 for formatting??